# table row sum to html with js

Tags: javascript, html-table, innerhtml

I've made a simple table with only two rows that allow the user to input numbers.

The numbers for each row are added and return two sums, one for each row.
The problem is that I can only make this work as long as I console.log it. I can't get it right when returning it to my html.

I know there are similar posts here, but they all use jQuery or something that I don't really think fit for my problem. But if you find this a duplicate I'm truly sorry.

Thank you for your time!

```js
// Reference the first (and only for the moment) form
let f0 = document.forms[0];
// Collect all form controls of f0
let F = f0.elements;

f0.onchange = editData;

function editData() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#tableID");
  allrows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let sum = document.querySelector("#sum");

  for (i = 1; i < allrows.length; i++) {
    rowTotal = 0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input").length; ii++) {
      rowTotal =
        rowTotal + Number(allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[ii].value);
    }

    sum.innerHTML = rowTotal; // I can see this won't work, but I can't seem to find a solution

    console.log(rowTotal); // this is the total of each row
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dbc5a7;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="F0">
      <table id="tableID">
        <caption>
          header
        </caption>
        <!-- First Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 1</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Row</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Second Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Input Row 1</th>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="0" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="3" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p id="sum">0</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Third Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Input Row 2</th>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="5" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="0" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p id="sum">0</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in your html. You should never do this. I think that's what's breaking it. (only the first such element will ever be updated.)

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you very much. I accepted, upvoted, and thanked :) Just one issue tho... when I inspect it, I get an error message saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLFormElement.editData". Any solution to that? Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind. I got it solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not give two elements the same id; ids are meant to be unique on a page. You can instead use a class and use `.querySelector` on each row to get the element.

If you gave each `p` element used to display the total the class "sum", your code to display the result would simply be:

```
allrows[i].querySelector('.sum').innerHTML = rowTotal;
```

Demo:

```js
// Reference the first (and only for the moment) form
let f0 = document.forms[0];
// Collect all form controls of f0
let F = f0.elements;

f0.onchange = editData;

function editData() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#tableID");
  allrows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let sum = document.querySelector("#sum");

  for (let i = 1; i < allrows.length; i++) {
    rowTotal = 0;
    for (let ii = 0; ii < allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input").length; ii++) {
      rowTotal =
        rowTotal + Number(allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[ii].value);
    }

    allrows[i].querySelector('.sum').innerHTML = rowTotal;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dbc5a7;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="F0">
      <table id="tableID">
        <caption>
          header
        </caption>
        <!-- First Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 1</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Phase 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Row</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Second Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Input Row 1</th>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="0" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="3" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="sum">0</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Third Row -->
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Input Row 2</th>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="5" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="0" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" value="2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="sum">0</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```